# How to call Go callback function From JNA?

Tags: java, go, jna

I am learning Go and want to use it with JNA.

However, I have a problem.

Go code:

```golang
package main

import "C"

//export Sum
func Sum(i int, b int, callback func(out int)) {
    callback(i + b)
}

func main() {

}
```

Generated h file (end is) :

```c
/* End of boilerplate cgo prologue.  */

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

extern void Sum(GoInt i, GoInt b, void* callback);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

How to call this function from JNA in Java?

I wrote in Java:

```java
interface MyLibrary : Library {
    fun Sum(i : Int,b : Int,callback : MyCallback)
}

interface MyCallback : com.sun.jna.Callback {
    fun callback (out : Int)
}
```

But this does not work.

Comment: By the way, [*JEP 442: Foreign Function & Memory API (Third Preview)*](https://openjdk.org/jeps/442)